# Allow members to create groups on my site

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, posts, members, groupby

I am currently building my first Wordpress site. I want to be able to do the following:

- User arrives on page listing all the available groups
- User joins group if he finds what he likes
- If he doesn't find what he likes, he can create a new group and post it on the same page

Any advice here? Thanks everybody !

Here's an example wireframe:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.mockflow.com/app/wireframepro/company/Ca5da46834ce9573670ea34b79da0d8a0/projects/M79623675c0572761f400b7266af8de811587389099264/pages/11eaaaf342e94bc5826431b70c810e54/image/11eaaaf342e94bc5826431b70c810e54.png

Comment: What makes the groups?  A plugin?  There are a lot of permutations as to how your answer could be solved because any answer with the current details will be purely on conjecture and assumption.  If you already have a utility for the 'Groups' function, then provide that information in the question.  If you've built the utility yourself then show the code in your question.  As it stands now it'd be really hard to provide you with answer

Comment: Let me reclarify, i want to build a page where a user can create his own group. The group is about his favourite hobby with a series of metadata. The groups then shows up on the "groups page" where other users can join that group or can create a new one if they didn't find the hobby they liked.

Comment: Here's a wirframe of what I'm trying to do, any help would be appreciated !https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.mockflow.com/app/wireframepro/company/Ca5da46834ce9573670ea34b79da0d8a0/projects/M79623675c0572761f400b7266af8de811587389099264/pages/11eaaaf342e94bc5826431b70c810e54/image/11eaaaf342e94bc5826431b70c810e54.png

Comment: Mike, check this out:  https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/

BuddyPress is a rich WordPress plugin with a whole segment of extendable plugins and stuff available.  That may be what you're after.  It works with groups and joining, creating them and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BuddyPress to create groups, manage groups, allow users to join groups and search them.  BuddyPress is like a Social Network plugin for WordPress.  Has it's own sub-section/ecosystem of plugins and add-ons and code snippets that you can apply.

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/

There's an active developer community and lots of documentation too:
https://codex.buddypress.org